# Do you know some successors of the designer Alexey Brodovitch?

Tags: editorial-design

I think his work is amazing and I would explore some designer inspired by his design's approach, here an example of Alexey Brodovitch work:

[image]

Comment: I don't know any successor, but if you're interested in publishing design I recommend you to visit http://newspagedesigner.org. It's a site where designers from all over the world upload and share pages from their designs.

In its Portfolio tab → Featured Pieces → View all, you can find excellent quality works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you know some successors of the designer Alexey Brodovitch?
>
> I think his work is amazing and I would explore some designer inspired by his design's approach.

There are many, perhaps you might be interested in reading a bit about him, otherwise simply skip to the bold text and links below.

- IconOfGraphics has an [article on Alexey Brodovitch](http://www.iconofgraphics.com/alexey-brodovitch/).
- The [AIGI](https://www.aiga.org/about/) (American Institute of Graphic Arts) website has a [biography](https://www.aiga.org/medalist-alexeybrodovitch) written by Andy Grundberg, in recognition of his 1987 AIGA Medal.
- The [ADC](http://adcglobal.org/about/what-is-adc/) ([Art Directors Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Directors_Club_of_New_York) of New York) has an [article](http://adcglobal.org/hall-of-fame/alexey-brodovitch/) which says:

  > ... While in Philadelphia, Brodovitch began actively to resume his role as an advertising designer. Some of that work was done for N. W. Ayer with [Charles Coiner](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_T._Coiner), the esteemed creative director of the agency.
  >
  > In 1934, Carmel Snow, the editor of Harper’s Bazaar, foresaw the genius of Alexey Brodovitch and urged him to become the art director of her magazine. Brodovitch accepted and remained with Harper’s Bazaar for twenty-five years. ...
  >
  > To this end, he introduced many of the best photographers, artists and designers of the time: **Irving Penn, Cartier Bresson, Christian Berard, Jean Cocteau, Richard Avedon, A. M. Cassandre, Felix Topolski** and **Saul Steinberg** — all of whom enriched the popular culture with their sophisticated vision of our universe. In his personal aesthetic, Brodovitch lived for change. Each editorial achievement was a fact; repetition was banality. Marvin Isreal, a painter and designer who was an associate of Brodovitch at Bazaar, saw him as a man “obsessed with change. Each issue had in some way to be unique…I think it was a state of perpetual optimism.” Harper’s Bazaar, in short, became a center for the most fertile minds in editorial visual communication.
  >
  > Not long after Brodovitch came to New York, he reestablished his lively design laboratory at the New School. In addition to his other consuming activities, he functioned as art director for Saks Fifth Avenue and I. Miller. Many of his former students served as his assistants under the master’s unyielding critical standards.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > The list of those who revere him as a teacher reads like an elite who’s who. **Irving Penn, Richard Avedon, Art Kane, Henry Wolf, Bruce Davidson, Steve Frankfurt**, and **Robert Gage** are but a few who acknowledge their debt to Brodovitch. In 1959, his ultimate document was the superbly fashioned book “[Observations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observations_(book))” which Brodovitch designed in collaboration with Richard Avedon, whom he regarded as one of his most gifted protégés. In that book, Truman Capote, assessing Brodovitch as a shaper and molder of the visual domain, wrote: “He brings a boldness bordering on revolution, an eye unexcelled, and in educated terms, a taste for vanguard experiment that has been for thirty-plus years the awe, and possibly the making, of all who have ever had the privilege of his guidance.”
- Eric Kim and his "[Masters of Photography](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/masters-of-photography/)" webbook mention [Alexey Brodovitch](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2017/07/27/alexey-brodovitch-learn-from-the-masters/) on his [blog](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/). That article (which is **[Open Source](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/open-source/)**), lists many that he influenced. It says:

  > "Alexey Brodovitch is an individual who has had a MASSIVE influence in the history of photography, design, and much more.
  >
  > He influenced Robert [Frank](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2013/01/07/timeless-lessons-street-photographers-can-learn-from-robert-franks-the-americans/), Richard [Avedon](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2014/09/26/5-lessons-richard-avedon-taught-street-photography/), Harpers Bazaar, and brought modern typography and design to America.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > ... But it was through his singular and rigid style, that we weren’t for him, we would not have innovations such as:
  >
  > 1. White space: He used so much white space in his design and layouts, that he was called racist.
  >
  > 2. Combining text and images: believe it or not, before him, designers never combined text and images.
  > 3. Radically cropping images: he would radically crop images and photos to make dynamic and edgy layout and spreads.
  > 4. He innovated by creating book and magazine covers with only text in big and bold letters — another innovation.
  > 5. One of the first designers to integrate color into layouts and covers.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Photographer and filmmaker, Jerry [Schatzberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Schatzberg), tells a story of when he took a course with Brodovitch:
  >
  > `“He taught me something that I’ve always remembered: After we did the initial assignment, he contradicted what he said the first week, and I said, ‘Okay’. The next week, he contradicted what he said the second week. We went through 10 weeks of contradicting and I thought maybe he was drunk. At the end, he said, ‘You may think I’ve contradicted myself, but there’s no one way to do anything.’”`
  >
  > Lesson: you gottta contradict yourself to innovate. You gotta realize that photography, design, and art is constantly in FLUX. There will never be one true way to do something.
  >
  > To innovate, you got to destroy the past, to pave new roads.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > The course was organized as follows:
  >
  > The lab was split into two sections per week, one for design and one for photography. The workshops were immensely popular, and it was not unusual for more than sixty people to show up to his class on the first night. Among the photographers who attended his classes were Diane Arbus, Eve Arnold, David Attie, Richard Avedon, Harvey Lloyd, Hiro, Lisette Model, Garry Winogrand and Tony Ray-Jones.
  >
  > Alexey Brodovitch taught Diane [Arbus](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2012/10/15/11-lessons-diane-arbus-can-teach-you-about-street-photography/), Eve Arnold, Richard [Avedon](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2014/09/26/5-lessons-richard-avedon-taught-street-photography/), Lisette [Model](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2017/07/25/lisette-model-learn-from-the-masters-of-photography/), Garry [Winogrand](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2012/08/20/10-things-garry-winogrand-can-teach-you-about-street-photography/), and Tony [Ray-Jones](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2013/11/16/dont-take-boring-photos-13-tips-for-street-photographers-from-tony-ray-jones/) … who are all titans who have influenced contemporary photography on a massive scale.
  >
  > Probably the biggest influence was on Irving [Penn](http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2017/07/25/irving-penn-part-ii-learn-from-the-masters-of-photography/), one of the greatest portrait photographers in history.
  >
  > Even read this insightful conversation: Avedon and Penn ([.PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/failg9r942bvgfh/avedon%20and%20Irving%20Penn%20conversation.pdf?dl=0)).
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Also to note, Alexey commissioned photographers such as Henri [Cartier-Bresson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Cartier-Bresson), Martin [Munkacsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Munk%C3%A1csi), and Man [Ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Ray) in unique and experimental locations to make experimental photos.

Kim's article also includes quotes from associates, students, and images of his work.